# VUEJS3 / TYPESCRIPT View data imported from an API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I try to display the data in my template but nothing is displayed,I have a blank screen, using Vue js 3 with typescript (and im new...)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img :src="datas[0].image">
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';

interface datasInterface {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    price: number,
    description: string,
    category: string,
    image: string,
    rating: {
        rate: number,
        count: number
    }
}

const datas = ref<datasInterface[]>([])

onMounted(async () => {
    const dataAsync = await (await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')).json()
    datas.value = dataAsync
    console.log(datas.value);
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your template with the following `v-if` condition

```
<template v-if="datas.length > 0">
    <div>
        <img :src="datas[0].image">
    </div>
</template>
```

Your code was resulting in a error in the console..

[image]

Basically, vue was trying to render before data is available. So this v-if condition should solve your problem.